# Azure Ubuntu VM - Waagent configuration

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04, azure-virtual-machine

I have on my Ubuntu 16.04 VM in `/etc/sudoers.d/waagent` the configuration that is unwanted. Even if I log as root, root has only read permission.

How should I safely edit configuration for Azure **waagent**?

I wanna change 
`someuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`
to 
`someuser ALL=(ALL) ALL`

Can I simply add write permission for root and edit the file or need I do it in different way via Azure commands?

I would like to prevent the case when `sudo` configuration is damaged due fact I have no physical access to VM and cannot fix it.

Comment: not sure what do you mean, sudo works fine on azure vms

Comment: @4c74356b41 Azure installed Waagent and set the rule that if "someuser" uses sudo command, then he does not need password. I would like to change this behaviour. I need to force "someuser" to use his password when he uses sudo command

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, I think there is no more safe way to edit the /etc/sudoers.d/waagent(in my side, the file name is /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users). The file just can be edited with the root permission. If you use the root to edit then everything works in the same way.

So I suggest you can just use the root user, add the write permission and edit the file as you want. But do not forget to change the permission back, in other words, remove the write permission when everything is OK.

Comment: Thank you. The problem I got in my test VM is that first time I've tried to edit the file as root, even if there was no W permission and I got to corrupted state. Thus I cannot use sudo because sudo configuration became corrupted. Do you know whether editation without W permission can cause this issue?

Comment: It's possible to damage the file even without the W permission If you have the root permission. So you should be very careful to do everything with the root permission, it's better to backup before you take the action.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

Use `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/waagent`

Long answer:

When editing sudoers files, always use `visudo`. It is a `vi` editor, but includes built-in checks to prevent you from corrupting the file and will allow you to save the file even though there's no write permissions on the file (assuming you run it as root). Changing the permissions on the file to allow write access and using a normal text editor is a bad idea. Too easy to forget to change it back and one misplaced symbol or misspelled word can corrupt the file. That's why there is no write permission by default - to act as a check to prevent unwanted modifications that could potentially render your system unusable.